# Finding the three largest elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array with 4 randomly generated elements (using Python):

```
pa = np.random.normal(10, 5, 4)
```

I can find the largest element by doing:

```
ml = np.max(pa)
mll = np.where(pa == ml)
print(mll)
```

I'm wondering how can I find the 2nd and 3rd elements in this array? Also, my current output looks like:

```
(array([0]),)
```

Is there a way I can get a pure numerical output (0)? Thanks!

Update: Sorry for the previous confusion, I want to find the index of the 2nd and 3rd largest element, but all the answers so far are very helpful to me. Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want the largest values or the indexes of the largest values?

Comment: heapq.nlargest?

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the comment! I want the indexes of the largest values:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the three largest of the four values, then you can just find all the values that are greater than the minimum value. You can use [`argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html?highlight=argwhere#numpy.argwhere) to get just an array of indexes:

```
import numpy as np

pa = np.random.normal(10, 5, 4)
ml = np.min(pa)
mll = np.argwhere(pa > ml)
print(mll)
```

Sample output:

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [3]]
```

To flatten that output, convert to an array and [`flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
mll = np.array(np.nonzero(pa > ml)).flatten()
print(mll)
```

Sample output:

```
[0 1 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list is small enough, you can just sort it and grab the last 3 elements of a sorted list.

```py
np.sort(pa)[-3:]
```

However this will scale badly compared to a more bespoke search algorithm which doesn't care about ordering and only cares about the top 3 elements.

You can convert the array to a list via `.tolist()`. Any formatting from there is pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Sort your list:

`sorted_list = sorted(pa)`

Get the second and third largest value:

`print(sorted_list[-2])` and `print(sorted_list[-3])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 3, 2, 10, 4, 5])

ezAns = arr.argsort()[-3:][::-1] #nlog(n) will give top 3 elements location

ans = np.argpartition(arr, -3)[-3:] #linear time, you will get top 3 elements location but not in order
print(ezAns, ans)

ansVal = np.array([arr[i] for i in ezAns])
print(ansVal)
```

```
[3 5 4] [4 5 3] <<Indeces
[10  5  4] <<Values
```

Some interesting stuff I found: `argpartition` runs in linear time, O(n), using the introselect algorithm

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! That's really helpful:)